# How to solve "Warning: mysqli_real_connect() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given" error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

When I use this code below, it works just fine.

```
$db_conn = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD,DATABASE);
```

But when I want to create an interactive MySQL connection with this code below.

```
$db_conn = mysqli_real_connect(HOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD,DATABASE,$flags=MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE);
```

I got this error.

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in <source_file> on line 74
```

How can I use `mysqli_real_connect()` the right way?

Comment: Check the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php)

Comment: `mysqli_real_connect ( mysqli $link [, string $host [, string $username [, string $passwd [, string $dbname [, int $port [, string $socket [, int $flags ]]]]]]] ) : bool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php):

> mysqli_real_connect() needs a valid object which has to be created by function [mysqli_init()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.init.php).

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$db_conn = mysqli_real_connect($mysqli, HOSTNAME, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD,DATABASE, 3306, null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Object oriented style:-**

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

`mysqli_real_connect()` function differs from `mysqli_connect()`

`mysqli_real_connect()` needs a valid object which has to be created by function `mysqli_init()`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -2):

Try this..

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'db_user', 'db_pass', 'db_name');
```

Where:
db_name represent database name
db_pass represent database password